# Randomly putting things in buckets, computing overflow probability (Basic probability question)

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

**Setting:**
Assume I have $n$ buckets, where each can hold $w$ balls and initially there is one ball in each bucket. I do the following. I keep taking one ball from a random bucket and I put it into another random bucket. I do this $l$ times. I want to figure out with what probability one of the buckets will overflow, i.e. what the probability is that at some point I try to put more than $w$ balls into some bucket.
Furthermore, I would like to know how large the buckets need to be s.t. the probability of such an overflow is below a threshold.

**Question:**
I have trouble deciding what the correct approach to this problem is and it's somehow not clear to me how, generally, to decide what approach to take. There are several methods that seem somewhat unrelated, yet useful for this problem.

**Approaches:**
For instance, I could look at an arbitrary, but fixed bucket and try to use the binomial formula to compute the probability that I will put $k$ out of $l$ balls into a specific bucket. However, I'm not sure how to consider the fact that I don't just put balls into buckets, but also remove them randomly. Also, I'm not sure whether looking at one bucket is really the same as looking at all of them.

Another, to me seemingly totally independent, approach would be to compute the expected value for the number of balls in a bucket (which should be 1) and then use the Chernoff bound to bound the probability that a specific bucket will overflow. Here, I'm not sure which Chernoff bound to use. There seem to be several very similar formulas, but I don't really understand the differences. Would I get some probability bound that depends on the number of iterations of my experiment, i.e. how often I randomly relocate a ball into some bucket?

Comment: @par I'm guessing OP wants to know the probability of overflowing in $k$ or less steps, otherwise the problem becomes trivial. OP, could you weigh in on this?

Comment: Yes, I think the overflow probability should be parameterized by the number of times I randomly reassign a ball to a new bin. So for instance, in my first approach I implicitly defined the number of rounds to be $l$.

Comment: Hi again - I don't think you'll notified automatically when an answer on your question is edited, so here's this: I've just updated my answer to give a  full solution (although not in closed form). Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

*EDIT: This is a combinatoric/thermodynamic approach. I will keep my first answer though, found below, because it was fun to write.*

---

We have $N$ buckets and balls. After some number of steps, the system is in equilibrium (it starts out pretty much in equilibrium). In equilibrium, all microstates are assumed to be equally likely, but some macrostates are more abundant than others. By counting the total number of microstates, $\Omega$, as well as the number of microstates in which there is at least one bucket with $w$ or more balls in it, $\Omega_{\geq w},$ we can obtain the probability of having at least one bucket with $w$ or more balls in it, given as

$$P_{\geq w}=\Omega_{\geq w}/\Omega.$$

Now all we have to do is count these two.

$\Omega$ can be found via a simple application of [stars and bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCsUx.png), giving $$\Omega=\binom{2N-1}{N}.$$

Figuring out $\Omega_{\geq w}$ is much more tricky. In fact, I couldn't do it, so I asked a [question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy) myself, the result of which (courtesy of Brian M. Scott) was

$$\Omega_{\geq w}=\sum_{i=1}^N(-1)^{i+1}\binom{N}i\binom{2N-1-iw}{N-1},$$

where any binomial coefficient with a negative argument is defined to be zero.

So

\begin{align}
P_{\geq w}&=\Omega_{\geq w}/\Omega \\
{} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N(-1)^{i+1}\binom{N}i\binom{2N-1-iw}{N-1}}{\binom{2N-1}{N}}.
\end{align}

You can see it plotted here for some different values of $N$ and $w$:

$N=30,w=10$:

[image]

$N=30,w=15$:

[image]

$N=30,w=25$:

[image]

Note that only $w$ really does something to the shape of the function. Compare, for instance, the following plot (in which $N=100,w=10$) with the first (in which $N=30,w=10$):

So there you have it! :)

[image]

---

---

---

**Old answer:**

*Note: I'm a bit unsure of this approach (it seems too easy!), so if you, dear reader, would like to exercise some peer-review, I'd be grateful!*

---

Consider one of the $n$ buckets. Let $X_t\leq n$ be the number of balls in this bucket after $t$ steps, with $X_0=1$.

In the $(t+1)$th step, there is a probability $\frac{1}{n-1}\left(1-\frac{X_t}{n}\right)$ that a ball is added, and a probability $\frac{X_t}{n}$ that a ball is removed.

We thus have

\begin{align}
\langle X_1 \rangle&=\frac{1}{n-1}\left(1-\frac{X_0}{n}\right)(X_0+1)+\frac{X_0}{n}(X_0-1) \\
\\[-1pt]
&=\frac{n+X_0^2(n-2)}{n(n-1)}
\end{align}

We see that, given some number $X_{t-1}$, we have 
$$\langle X_t \rangle=\frac{n+X_{t-1}^2(n-2)}{n(n-1)}.$$

If we don't know the exact value of $X_{t-1}$, we should instead used the expected value of it, so we get

$$\langle X_t \rangle=\frac{n+\langle X_{t-1} \rangle^2 (n-2)}{n(n-1)},$$

which is a recursion that I unfortunately cannot solve. I can, however, do some numerical analysis, which shows that the expected value quickly drops to some value less than one. For instance, for $n=10$, the value $0.1122$ is reached after $t\sim 4$ (so very quickly), and it stays at that value thereafter, so it is a stable point.

We can find this stable point by finding the limit of our sequence. Since $\frac{n+x^2 (n-2)}{n(n-1)}$ is continuous, we have

\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} [a_k] \\
&= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left[\frac{n+a_{k-1}^2 (n-2)}{n(n-1)}\right] \\
&= \frac{n+\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\left[a_{k-1} \right]^2 (n-2)}{n(n-1)} \\
&= \frac{n+L^2 (n-2)}{n(n-1)} \quad \quad \implies \\
L&=\frac{n(n-1)-\sqrt{8n+n^2(n+1)(n-3)}}{2(n-2)},
\end{align}

so

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} [\langle X_t \rangle]=L.$$

$L(n)$ is a rather interesting function. You can see it below.

[image]

Note that $L(1)=\lim_{n\rightarrow 2}[L(n)]=1$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} [L(n)]=0$, all of which makes intuitive sense.

> **Now, what does all this say about your question?** Well, it seems that the probability for overflowing is vanishingly small, especially for large $n$, which is also what the [principle of maximum entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy) would suggest (the most likely state is one where the balls are "spread out" relatively evenly).

Comment: Hey thank you for the very detailed answer! I'll read it carefully in the next days and give you a proper answer.

Comment: @user2585160 My pleasure! :)

Comment: @user2585160 Hey again, did you ever get a chance to read it?

Comment: doing that right now! :D

Comment: @user2585160 Great! :D

Comment: It is not clear to me what the exact definition of the microstates in your solution is. As far as I understand, you count the number of ball to bin assignments ($\Omega_{\geq w}$), where I have at least $w$ balls in one of the bins, and then divide this by the total number of different assignments of balls to bins. This would then tell me what the probability of one bin having more than $w$ is if I throw balls randomly into the bins, but my question was about the worst case deviation from an "equlibrium" if I already have balls in the bins and I start randomly reassigning them one by one.

Comment: @user2585160 The idea of the microstate-approach is the assumption that all states are equally likely (which they are if you're rearranging in a truly random way). If you think about it, there is no difference between the scenario where you randomly throw all the balls in the bins all at once and the scenario in which you've been messing around with the system for some time. In either case the system will be in a random state, where counting the microstates that match a given macrostate (overflow) will give the probability of the macrostate.

Comment: Hm. It seems to make sense, but I found a paper that deals with this problem and I can't somehow relate your result with the results in the paper, for instance, they give different bounds for different relations between the number of bins and number of balls. Paper: http://wwwmayr.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/personen/raab/publ/balls.pdf. In theorem 1 page 3 they give a short description of their result.

What are the exact conditions under which analyzing one microstate allows me to argue some "randomized" process on top of it? Is there a proof for that?

Comment: @user2585160 I unfortunately don't have time to go through the paper (perhaps you could ask in chat if someone could compare my with their result?). *What are the exact conditions under which analyzing one microstate allows me to argue some "randomized" process on top of it? Is there a proof for that?* I'm not entirely sure what you mean, could you precise this? Btw, note that all macrostates can be reached after $N-1$ steps, after which the results here should be valid.

Comment: Basically it's not clear to me how to formally show/reason that analyzing the throwing balls in bins scenario is the same as the setting that I described in the question, where I randomly pick a ball and move it into another bin.

Comment: @user2585160  It should be obvious that the two ways of creating the distribution are the same if we let the number of steps go toward infinity, but obviously the balls can be considered randomly distributed after a finite number of steps. To get an idea of this value I'd throw a Monte-Carlo simulation after it.

Comment: @user2585160 Although, there is for sure a lot of research in the area of how many shuffles are needed to randomize a deck of cards, for instance, which is very related to this.